# How to serialize an Icon to a resource (.resx) file from Visual Studio Resource Editor?

Tags: visual-studio, resx

I am trying to add some icons to a .resx file in a VB.NET project in Visual Studio 2019. However, I want them to be serialized into the .resx file rather than referenced, in the same way that the Windows Forms designer does. But when I click "Add existing file" in the Resource Editor, it adds it to the resource file as a file reference, like this:

```
<data name="MyIcon.ico" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>Resources\MyIcon.ico;System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
</data>
```

How do I add it as raw data, serialized?

Comment: Select the added icon.  In the Properties window, change the "Persistence" property from Linked to Embedded.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that out. I'll write out the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To do this with any resource (except perhaps String), select the resource in the Resource Editor and in the Properties window, change the "Persistence" property from "Linked at compile time" to "Embedded in .resx".